# How to make the arXiv watermark clickable?

Tags: arxiv

How to make the watermark added by arxiv (left border in the first page) a clickable link? I can't figure out what package/option is needed.

Comment: It's automatically added. What makes you think that you can change that?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I was also skeptical, but, curiously enough, in the recent submissions I have found examples where it is clickable and examples where it is not. Hyperref does not seem to be the culprit, as one of those non-clickable submissions had other clickable hyperlinks.

Comment: [non-clickable](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.07230), [clickable](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.07169).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610844/make-the-arxiv-timestamp-a-clickable-hyperlink There is an answer on tex SE, but I cannot chose that as a duplicate - should we migrate and the tex SE people do the dupliacte close, or is it relevant enough for Academia SE to stay here?

Comment: @Sursula-they- Thank you for finding the question on TeX SE. No, if it's already there we shouldn't migrate it, but it's anyway off-topic here, so I've closed it.